# Database Design For android Application

Tags: mysql, database, oracle, sqlite, database-design

I want to create one android Application online product selling. 
I need database which maintain product and its categories as show below.

```
 1. category
 2. subcategories
 3. sub subcategories
```

n level categories.
I also want to maintain Google play like application rating database.
 how should i design database ?

Answer (score 0):

Google Play has categories and products in a structure similar to this:

```
Apps
    Games
        Arcade & Action
            Flying Simulator
            Ingress
        Brain & Puzzle
            The Room
            The Room Two
            Where's My Water?
            Cut the Rope
    Business
        OfficeSuite Por 7
        Docs To Go Premium Key
Books
    Arts & Entertainment
        Art
            Wuthering Heights
```

Create the following:

```
Table: category
Columns: category_id, category_name, parent_category_id

Table: product
Columns: product_id, product_name

Table: category_product
Columns: category_product_id, product_id, category_id
```

And insert data as follows:

**category table:**

```
1, Apps, null
2, Games, 1
3, Arcade & Action, 2
4, Brain & Puzzle, 2
5, Business, 1
7, Books, null
8, Arts & Entertainment, 7
9, Art, 8
```

**product table:**

```
100, Flying Simulator
101, Ingress
102, The Room
103, The Room Two
104, Where's My Water?
105, Cut the Rope
106, OfficeSuite Por 7
107, Docs To Go Premium Key
108, Wuthering Heights
```

**category_product:**

```
1000, 100, 3
1001, 101, 3
1002, 102, 4
1003, 103, 4
1004, 104, 4
1005, 105, 4
1006, 106, 5
1007, 107, 5
1008, 108, 9
```

You can do the same for ratings.  Create a **product_rating** table.